# TD tags stripped out of custom element table row

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have a table that has a custom element for the rows using `as-element`.

The table uses the element as follows:

```
<tbody>
  <tr as-element="personnel-row" repeat.for="person of personnel" person.bind="person" is-compact.bind="isCompact"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Personnel-row looks like this:

```
<template>
  <td if.bind="isCompact">${person.fullName}</td>
  <td if.bind="!isCompact">${person.lastName}</td>
  <td if.bind="!isCompact">${person.firstName}</td>
  <td if.bind="!isCompact">${person.middleInitial}</td>
  <td if.bind="!isCompact">${person.level}</td>
  <td>${person.primary}</td>
  <td if.bind="!isCompact">${person.status}</td>
  <td>${person.certification}</td>
  <td if.bind="!isCompact"><a route-href="route: personnel-detail; params.bind: {id:person.id}">View</a></td>
</template>
```

What's happening is that when it gets rendered, all of the `td`s are stripped out and all of the interpolated strings are directly inside the `tr`.

I'm aware of issues with having the wrong stuff inside `tbody`, or anything besides `td`s inside `tr`s, but this is new to me. What could be causing this behavior?

**EDIT:** I apologize, I forgot to mention that this works fine in Edge and Chrome. The issue with the `td`s only happens in IE.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues. I've created a gist.run example here: https://gist.run/?id=72c95ceb3dcfd19008b7dadcb9afed27

Comment: @AshleyGrant I've uploaded a sample app that demonstrates the problem in IE. It works in other browsers. https://github.com/devingoble/AureliaIETableRepro

Comment: Awesome! I'll give it a look. The important thing for us to figure out is if the bug is in your code or our code. :-)

Comment: Alright, I'm seeing the error now. I'll look in to it after I finish up some other business. We're probably gonna have to file a bug on this.

Comment: @AshleyGrant was this filed and possibly fixed now?